# How do I select the Form's body html element in TMS Web Core?

Tags: html, delphi, document-body, tms-web-core

In short, I have a form that is named `MyForm`. Looking at the compiled HTML in the browser, I can see that the form is equal to the `body` tag. I can prove this by changing the form's color to blue and then I can clearly see the body tag has the background color of blue set on it.

So here's my Delphi code where I am trying to get the form's element and then setting a data attribute for it:

```
MyForm.element.setAttribute('data-test','form');
```

This results in an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')
> [image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')]

So it's not finding the `element` of the form. I can prove this by simply doing a `console.log(MyForm.element)` and that returns a `null`.

Doing this same code on any other component works perfectly fine except on the form.

How can I select the form's element (body tag) using Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `MyForm.element` doesn't work. I feel like it should work, but in any case. I found that you can use `document.body` to get the body tag instead of `MyForm.element`.

So the code to set a data attribute for the body would be:

```
document.body.setAttribute('data-test','form');
```

And that's working fine now.

Comment: I suspect that you try to access the form element while the form is being created. That's probably too early. You might have better luck when trying to access the element at a later time.

Comment: @NineBerry I just tested it. It's still not working at a later stage. If I do `.element` for any other component, then it finds the component except for the form.